# Query Optimisation on table with 3,500,000 rows, indexing

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a table of products which is approx 3,500,000 items. The table has a fulltext index on the column named title.

The following query example is taking up to 4 seconds which is completely unacceptable and am looking at ways in which to optimise... ideas/advice appreciated.

Basically; which columns should be indexed, should I be pulling so many columns out individually or is it faster to pull all columns (there are 23 total) etc etc

Query example:

```
SELECT PRid, title, Artist, author, actors, imageURL, prodcat, lowprice,
highprice, prodcatID, description from products where
((MATCH(title) AGAINST ('+blue +top' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) order by
userrating desc limit 500
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first port of call should always be `EXPLAIN` to see what MySQL is doing. I suspect that sorting on something other than the match score probably doesn't help - I don't think mysql would be able to use an index on userrating for sorting at the same time as the full text index.

Last time I used MySQL full text search (a few years ago admittedly) I found that it just wasn't fast enough beyond a million rows or so. You may want to consider a full text search engine such as cloudsearch, elasticsearch, solr or sphinx.

Answer (score 1):

How many unique combinations of "title" are there? You may find it worth while putting that data into a lookup table with a foreign key in the main data table.

Then when querying your data, you join the two tables together and apply the filter to the smaller table, which will take less time to apply. The join then happens on a numeric field, which you can index in your main data table.

This will be significantly quicker than doing a text filter on 3.5m rows. Assuming there are many duplications within that data, your lookup table could be a fraction of this size.

You will also find that reading through the main data will be faster if there is a numeric instead of a text field, as the rows will be smaller, and therefore the whole data size smaller.

Getting all of the text based data into lookups will make everything even faster, as the main data table could then become fixed format instead of dynamic, meaning that indexes are more efficient when locating data within the table.

Hope that helps!

Dave